# Updating individual elements of a sparse matrix in R is very slow - how can I do it faster?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

The `profvis` analysis of a script that uses a sparse matrix revealed that the update of the sparse matrix elements is the slowest step in the process, by 1 order of magnitude.
I need to understand if I can do this better (and especially faster); I would appreciate if someone could please advise where to look or provide suggestions.

Here is some `R` code that reproduces the 'critical' part of my script:

```
require(Matrix)
m <- new("dgCMatrix", i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
9L, 10L), p = c(0L, 5L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 
40L, 43L), Dim = c(11L, 11L), Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")), x = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), factors = list())

system.time(for (i in 1:10000) m[7,c(1,5,6,7)] <- c(0,0,1,0))
```

On my laptop, this takes about 7 s.
*[BTW, obviously I do not repeat the same operation 10000 times; the rows and columns that are updated change each time, but indeed it happens a very large number of times. I did the above to simulate the operations that are performed in the real script and to get a measurable time that can be compared with faster solutions that might come up.]*

Any ideas/suggestions?

PS
I had a similar problem in the past, but for a different case; and I can't find it back, as my activity history only goes back to a few months ago.

**EDIT**
OK, I found out how to retrieve all my old posts, and discovered that the problem I am describing here was not covered.

**EDIT 2** - following up from discussion with / suggestions by pseudospin

```
require(Matrix)
require(data.table)

m <- new("dgCMatrix", i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
                            7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 
                            1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
                            9L, 10L), p = c(0L, 5L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 
                                            40L, 43L), Dim = c(11L, 11L), Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
                                                                                            "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                                                                                                                         "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")), x = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), factors = list())

ms <- summary(m)
ms <- ms[order(ms$i,ms$j),]
msdt <- data.table(ms)

time_1 <- system.time(for (i in 1:5000) m[7,c(1,5,7,9)] <- c(0,0,1,0))
cat("\ntime_1 =", time_1)

time_2 <- system.time(for (i in 1:5000) ms[(ms$i == 7) & (ms$j %in% c(1,5,7,9)),"x"] <- c(0,0,1,0))
cat("\ntime_2 =", time_2)

time_3 <- system.time(for (i in 1:5000) msdt[(i == 7) & (j %in% c(1,5,7,9)),"x" := c(0,0,1,0)])
cat("\ntime_3 =", time_3)
```

which gave:

```
time_1 = 2.86 0 2.86 NA NA
time_2 = 0.23 0 0.24 NA NA
time_3 = 1.2 0.02 1.22 NA NA
```

Maybe this example is misleading, though, because normally I would have much higher max values of `i` and `j`, so perhaps subsetting a `data.table` will be much more efficient than subsetting a `data.frame`.
To be tested with my real data...

**EDIT 3** - trial with real data, including testing the dense matrix method as suggested by GKi

Real data (too large to paste here): `m` is a sparse 5828 x 5828 matrix; 302986 / 33965584 = 0.9% of it is filled (hence its sparseness). It occupies 4.4 MB. The corresponding dense matrix `dm = as.matrix(m)` occupies 272.5 MB.

Testing the `sparseMatrix` (1), `data.frame` (2), `data.table` (3) and dense matrix (4) updating methods shows the following:

```
time_1 = 10.25 3.19 13.72 NA NA
time_2 = 41.32 10.94 52.52 NA NA
time_3 = 35.64 7.44 43.34 NA NA
time_4 = 0.05 0.03 0.08 NA NA
```

So, in agreement with GKi's results, the dense matrix method is by far the fastest, but at the cost of huge memory storage.
On the other hand, the simulated data used originally gave very different results for the `sparseMatrix` method, which with real data is instead the second fastest among these 4.

Unfortunately it looks like a catch-22 situation: to have fast editing I need to use a dense matrix, but a dense matrix takes far too much memory, so I need to use a sparse matrix, which however is slow to edit :(

Maybe I will need to reconsider the original suggestion by pseudospin, and use sparse vectors for each row of the matrix. For that I will need to find out how I can refer to a stored `R` object by an indirect reference (string).

Comment: I guess this is 'slow' because of the way sparse matrices are stored - it has to look up each element to see if it is there before changing it, whereas traditional matrices just find the memory to change using an offset calculated from the indices. I think your problem might need a bigger picture solution to make it faster.

Comment: I see, thanks. I wonder if replacing the whole matrix row rather than a few elements in the row would be better?

Comment: Here's [a nice intro](https://slowkow.com/notes/sparse-matrix/) to how they're stored. Based on this editing sparse matrices directly is just not efficient - it's probably making a full copy each time you edit a subset of elements (whether one element or a row).

Comment: :( perhaps then I would be better off if I used the sparse matrix summary data.frame (i,j,x) and subset and edited it? Maybe using data table for speed?

Comment: Not sure it'll be possible to implement editable sparse matrices using `data.table` any better than the `Matrix` package. It'd probably take some thought about your actual project to work out the best approach but, at a guess, perhaps storing the rows as separate sparse vectors might be the efficient way to go?

Comment: OK, thanks. I ran some tests. I will edit my post to show them.

Comment: Using sparse vectors is an idea, except that it works well only when I need to edit individual rows. There are other operations where I need to take column sums of multiple rows, and then the sparse matrix is very handy.

Comment: Maybe try instead of `Matrix` `slam` or `spray`?

Comment: @GKi : do you think the update of sparse matrix elements is faster in these other packages? Also, note that I make my final sparse matrix, like m above, by cross product of a sparse matrix A by its transpose, and A in turn comes from xtabs. So there would be some conversion cost, I guess.

Comment: I tried slam. Faster than Matrix' sparse matrix, but same performance as data.table, at least on these data. I still need to understand why the standard data.frame subsetting seems the best here; I am pretty sure data.table is meant to perform much better on such tasks. I will try with a larger sparse matrix.

Answer (score 2):

A comparison of different methods. Note that the methods *DataFrame*, *DataTable* and *FastMatch* will work only in case you are overwriting existing values in the sparse matrix but not when you insert new values.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(list = fun, control=list(order="block"))
#Unit: microseconds
#         expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval   cld
# SparseMatrix 618.307 623.1795 639.38102 627.2525 643.3895 1021.301   100     e
#  DenseMatrix   1.178   1.2210   1.36957   1.2635   1.3435    7.060   100 a    
#         Slam 259.703 264.3945 270.57151 265.9780 268.0745  426.610   100   c  
#        Spray 422.129 427.1310 463.21071 434.0705 440.6025 2880.787   100    d 
#    DataFrame  37.031  37.7910  38.98143  38.1660  38.6255   73.283   100  b   
#   DataFrameB  16.928  17.4480  17.85553  17.6910  18.0155   28.859   100 ab   
#   DataFrameC  21.007  21.7170  22.68689  21.9600  22.3735   38.175   100 ab   
#    DataTable 283.409 288.5710 299.43498 292.8395 301.1255  500.484   100   c  
#    FastMatch  40.138  40.7885  42.33623  41.2165  41.6575   82.274   100  b   
#         List   2.703   2.7900   3.28163   2.8535   2.9770   13.375   100 a    
#  Environment   2.157   2.2055   2.29915   2.2575   2.3340    4.211   100 a    

library(bench)
mark(exprs = fun, check = FALSE)
## A tibble: 11 x 13
#   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 SparseMatrix 624.43µs 651.98µs     1487.    1.65KB    10.4    712     5
# 2 DenseMatrix    1.61µs   1.86µs   490003.        0B    49.0   9999     1
# 3 Slam         261.46µs 271.96µs     3606.     7.2KB     8.24  1750     4
# 4 Spray        424.08µs 439.86µs     2206.    8.16KB    10.4   1063     5
# 5 DataFrame     37.26µs  40.03µs    24378.    2.08KB     9.75  9996     4
# 6 DataFrameB    18.25µs  19.72µs    49447.     1.7KB     9.89  9998     2
# 7 DataFrameC    22.72µs  24.82µs    39142.      840B    11.7   9997     3
# 8 DataTable    288.24µs 300.25µs     3252.   18.34KB     8.24  1579     4
# 9 FastMatch     41.05µs  43.73µs    22292.    2.46KB    11.2   9995     5
#10 List            3.4µs   3.71µs   257225.        0B    25.7   9999     1
#11 Environment    2.82µs   3.11µs   306445.        0B     0    10000     0
```

Methods:

```
fun <- alist(
  SparseMatrix = m[7,c(1,5,6,7)] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, DenseMatrix = dm[7,c(1,5,6,7)] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, Slam = slm[7,c(1,5,6,7)] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, Spray = spm[7,c(1,5,6,7)] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, DataFrame = ms[(ms$j == 7) & (ms$i %in% c(1,5,6,7)),"x"] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, DataFrameB = ms$x[(ms$j == 7) & (ms$i %in% c(1,5,6,7))] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, DataFrameC = {i <- which(ms$j == 7); ms$x[i[ms$i[i] %in% c(1,5,6,7)]] <- c(0,0,1,0)}
, DataTable = msdt[(j == 7) & (i %in% c(1,5,6,7)),"x" := c(0,0,1,0)]
, FastMatch = mf[mf$j %fin% 7 & (mf$i %fin% c(1,5,6,7)),"x"] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, List = ml[["7"]][c("1","5","6","7")] <- c(0,0,1,0)
, Environment = me[["7"]][c("1","5","6","7")] <- c(0,0,1,0)
)
```

Data:

```
library(Matrix)
m <- new("dgCMatrix", i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
9L, 10L), p = c(0L, 5L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 32L, 35L, 38L, 
40L, 43L), Dim = c(11L, 11L), Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")), x = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), factors = list())

dm <- as.matrix(m) #Dense Matrix

library(slam)
slm <- as.simple_sparse_array(dm)

library(spray)
spm <- as.spray(dm)

ms <- summary(m)
ms <- ms[order(ms$i,ms$j),]

library(data.table)
msdt <- data.table(ms)

library(fastmatch)
mf <- ms

ml <- split(setNames(ms$x, ms$j), ms$i)

me <- list2env(ml, hash = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough analysis! I wish I could use a dense matrix... unfortunately due to the size of the problems I am dealing with, a dense matrix would crash `R` (memory). To give you an idea, I obtain it by cross-product of an (MxN) matrix by its transpose, where M can be 10000, 50000 or even millions. You can imagine what happens if you try to make a (1 million x 1 million) dense matrix. Most of its elements are zero, so it is ~inevitable to use a sparse matrix. I will try your benchmark with my real data and report it.

Comment: I have added a Variant of `data.frame` and also a version using `list` and `environment`.

Comment: (ﾟoﾟ) - I did not know about this `split` method! That's almost as good as a dense matrix! Not sure how it works, but if it can be implemented it's better than anything I have seen so far.

Comment: Have also a look at *environment* as it finds its elements by hash and not with a linear search like the *list*.